# Do "bore down" and "bear down" mean the same thing?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I have scratching my head over something I heard in a movie description:

> Their jaws drop as a globe of churning green light **bores down** to the earth in front of them.

I only know "bear down" as a phrasal verb meaning "press down", but here apparently the narration is in the present tense. "Bore" as a verb means *to make hole* or *to penetrate*, but "bore down" doesn't seem to be an idiomatic phrase. So why does it say **bores down** here? I am putting the [audio clip here for reference](https://clyp.it/f4y3p1kr) (available through an audio sharing site, Clyp).

Comment: It says "bores down *into* the earth".  The verb is **bore** not **bear** and it means to create a hole by drilling.  *down into the earth* gives the physical specifics of the drilling there. The drilling is on the vertical axis, like a water well.

Comment: In any event, the past tense of **bear** is **bore** never **bores**. There is no grammatical number marker in the past. Today I bear, yesterday I **bore**, and he, she, it, we, you, and they **bore**.